# Why haven't I received reputation points for some of the upvotes that one of my answers received?

Tags: support, reputation, answers, voting

I answered a question, namely [What are some useful ways to use Automator?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/33185/14601), but I have not received any reputation points for the 4 up-votes that it received. Am I misunderstanding some portion of the process or the rules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your linked answer is a community wiki post. One of the effects of this is that  you receive no reputation for the post, positive or negative. This is indicated by the different style of author link at the bottom of the post.

[image]

Answers can be made community wiki specifically using the [community wiki checkbox under the answer once you reach 10 reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/community-wiki), however in this case the answer was automatically converted to community wiki as the question is community wiki. There are extremely few community wiki questions on the site (0.12% of questions are community wiki at the moment).

There is no bug, this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). For more information about community wiki, see:

- [What are "Community Wiki" posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740)

Comment: Thank you very much, @grgarside. FWIW, I don't remember what in the interface indicated or determined that I should use the "bug" tag while I was writing my question. (I hope the question showed that I was admitting my ignorance, and did not assume that it was a bug.) But I was basically made to add the bug tag before I could submit it, even though I had supplied other tags.

Comment: @David All meta questions must be tagged with at least one of the dark grey required tags which are [meta-tag:discussion], [meta-tag:support], [meta-tag:bug] and [meta-tag:feature-request]. This is why those four tags pop up when focusing on the tag box (unlike the main site) and why a red alert appears when attempting to submit a meta question without a required tag. [Image of both UIs combined.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Hrkcc.png)